# Is there a macro to know if an architecture has an FPU in C/C++?

Tags: c++, math, embedded, fpu

I'm writing a project in C++ using GCC. Is there a macro, preferably a standard one, that can tell me whether or not the architecture I am compiling to has an FPU?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to know this.  Is it a performance thing?  You can always time some floating point operations to get some idea of that.

Comment: What's the use case? Any architecture without FPU would need a cross-compiler today anyway, so you will know the architecture because you need to explicitly state which target you compile to. So just add a define yourself?

Comment: Most architectures provides their own set of macros, for example RISC-V define `__riscv_flen` when there is a FPU available, and the value of the macro is the number of bits the FPU can handle, e.g. 64 for the D extension.

Comment: How would your code use this information?

Comment: @Adel There are various degrees of hardware support - maybe just +,-,*,/ but not sqrt, log, sin,...  Or maybe `sin()` supported for only the primary angle range and needs an extensive SW wrapper to handle a `double`.  FPU is not a simply true/false issue.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Unfortunately the (P)C and (P)C++ committees don't seem able to fathom that there exist systems without FPU and that the artificial requirements = "must support float.h" on a freestanding system forces every compiler vendor to quite needlessly come up with a whole software floating point lib for each such system, where using floating point doesn't make sense to begin with. There should have been a `__STDC_NO_FLOAT__` macro.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specified in the C++ standard. In general, the C++ standard does not cover hardware-specific attributes of (`std::thread::hardware_concurrency` would be a notable exception).